# what is difference between /etc/shadow and /etc/passwd

Tags: etc, passwd

Both files `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/passwd` seem to be the same, they just report some information about accounts. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Short answer**:

`passwd` stores general user info and `shadow` stores user passwd info.

**Somewhat longer answer**:

`passwd` is the file where the user information (like username, user ID, group ID, location of home directory, login shell, ...) is stored when a new user is created.

`shadow` is the file where important information (like an encrypted form of the password of a user, the day the password expires, whether or not the passwd has to be changed, the minimum and maximum time between password changes, ...) is stored when a new user is created.

Some interesting extra info: [passwd](https://web.archive.org/web/20140727153855/http://www.thegeekscope.com/linux-passwd-file-explained/) and [shadow](https://web.archive.org/web/20131225075704/http://www.thegeekscope.com/linux-shadow-file-explained/)

Comment: Also always useful to have a look at the man files for a command or utility. At the command line simply type: man passwd

Answer (score 4):

From [The Linux Documentation Project - 6.6. Linux Password & Shadow File Formats](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/shadow-file-formats.html):

> Traditional Unix systems keep user account information, including
> one-way hashed passwords, in a text file called `/etc/passwd`. As this
> file is used by many tools (such as `ls`) to display file ownerships,
> etc. by matching user id #'s with the user's names, the file needs to
> be world-readable. Consequentally, this can be somewhat of a security
> risk.
>
> Another method of storing account information, one that I always use,
> is with the shadow password format. As with the traditional method,
> this method stores account information in the `/etc/passwd` file in a
> compatible format. However, the password is stored as a single "x"
> character (ie. not actually stored in this file). A second file,
> called `/etc/shadow`, contains encrypted password as well as other
> information such as account or password expiration values, etc. The
> `/etc/shadow` file is readable only by the root account and is therefore
> less of a security risk.

Answer (score 3):

#### /etc/shadow

file stores actual password in encrypted format for user's account with additional properties related to user password i.e. it stores secure user account information. All fields are separated by a colon (:) symbol [FOR MORE](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcshadow-file/)

#### /etc/passwd

file stores essential information, which is required during login i.e. user account information. /etc/passwd is a text file, that contains a list of the system's accounts, giving for each account some useful information like user ID, group ID, home directory, shell, etc. [FOR MORE](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/)